# d3.js tree layout: collapsing other nodes when expanding one?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

On a tree layout using d3.js ([example](http://jsbin.com/okUxAvE/1/edit?js,output)), I'd like to collapse nodes that are not in the branch that has been clicked on.

For example, in the above demo, try the following:

1. click on "Parent 1" (Child 1 and Child 2 are shown)
2. click on "Child 1" (Child 1.1 is shown)
3. click on "Child 2" (Child 2.1 is shown)

Now you should see both the children of "Child 1" and "Child 2".

I would like to have the following happen:

1. click on "Parent 1" (Child 1 and Child 2 are shown)
2. click on "Child 1" (Child 1.1 is shown)
3. click on "Child 2" (Child 2.1 is shown, **Child 1.1 is hidden**)

So children of nodes other than on the "active" branch should be hidden.

How can I best approach this? (efficiently of course, as I'll be using a fairly large dataset)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple solution is to modify the click function such that if the node has a parent, the parent's children are each collapsed, but only if the child isn't the node that was clicked on.

```
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  // If the node has a parent, then collapse its child nodes
  // except for this clicked node.
  if (d.parent) {
    d.parent.children.forEach(function(element) {
      if (d !== element) {
        collapse(element);
      }
    });
  }
  update(d);
}
```

Updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/etIJABU/2/edit

Comment: That's the kind of simplicity I was looking for; I was worried I'd have to iterate all over the place, but indeed, only the children of the parent matter at any one time! Thank you.

Comment: it is not working when .json file is called, if the data are inside it is working, not working for external .Json

Comment: @mcbalaji, it might be a problem with your data. There's nothing I can think of that would make the code behave differently if the JSON is fetched from a remote source. Make sure you're taking the asynchronous nature of an external request into account.

Comment: @t.888, You solution seems great and it works nicely. But when I click on the sibling node to expand it, the other (currently expanded) node's children collapse with the animation as if they are collapsing inside the clicked node. Can we correct that somehow?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to collapse other nodes only when you click on nodes with children, add "&& d.children" in the second IF..

```
function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } 
        else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        if (d.parent && d.children) { //add here, 
          d.parent.children.forEach(function(element) {
        if (d !== element) {
        collapse(element);
        }});
      }
        update(d);
      }
```